# conditional operator with groupby in spark rdd level - scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am using `Spark 1.60` and `Scala 2.10.5`

I have a dataframe like this,

```
+------------------+
|id | needed       | 
+------------------+
|1  | 2            |                                                                                                                                    
|1  | 0            |
|1  | 3            |
|2  | 0            |
|2  | 0            |
|3  | 1            |
|3  | 2            |                                                                                                    
+------------------+
```

From this `df` I created an `rdd` like this,

```
 val  dfRDD = df.rdd
```

from my `rdd`, I want to group by `id` and count of `needed` is `> 0`.

((1, 2), (2,0), (3,2))

So, I tried like this,

```
val groupedDF = dfRDD.map(x =>(x(0), x(1) > 0)).count.redueByKey(_+_)
```

In this case, I am getting an error:

> error: value > is not a member of any

I need that in `rdd` level. Any help to get my desired output would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your `map` you're calling the `apply` *method* of **Row**, and as you can see in its [*scaladoc*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row), that *method* returns **Any** - and as you can see for the error and from the [*scaladoc*](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.5/#scala.Any) there is not such *method* `<` in Any

You can fix it using the `getAs[T]` method.

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark =
  SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df =
  List(
    (1, 2),
    (1, 0),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 0),
    (2, 0),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 2)
  ).toDF("id", "needed")

val rdd: RDD[(Int, Int)] = df.rdd.map(row => (row.getAs[Int](fieldName = "id"), row.getAs[Int](fieldName = "needed")))
```

From there you can continue with the aggregation, you have a few mistakes in your logic.
First, you don't need the `count` call.
And second, if you need to count the amount of times `"needed"` was greater than one you can't do `_ + _`, because that is the sum of needed values.

```
val grouped: RDD[(Int, Int)] = rdd.reduceByKey { (acc, v) => if (v > 0) acc + 1 else acc }

val result: Array[(Int, Int)] = grouped.collect()
// Array((1,3), (2,0), (3,2))
```

**PS:** You should tell your professor to upgrade to Spark 2 and Scala 2.11 ;)

## Edit

Using **case classes** in the above example.

```
final case class Data(id: Int, needed: Int)
val rdd: RDD[Data] = df.as[Data].rdd
val grouped: RDD[(Int, Int)] = rdd.map(d => d.id -> d.needed).reduceByKey { (acc, v) => if (v > 0) acc + 1 else acc }  
val result: Array[(Int, Int)] = grouped.collect()
// Array((1,3), (2,0), (3,2))
```

Comment: Quick question, is there a automated way instead of `val rdd: RDD[(Int, Int)]` to create an `rdd` from a dataframe? I am thinking if we have more than 50 or 100 columns, then it'll become tedious.

Comment: @user9431057 you can create a **case class** that represent your data _(they may have nested **case classes**, **Arrays**  and **Maps** too)_ and then you may convert the **DataFrame** to a **Dataset[C]**, _(where C is the name of the case class)_, using the `df.as[C]` _method_. I would use the **Dataset** since it gives you almost all the methods an **RDD** has with almost all the _optimizations_ of a **DataFrame** - but if you need the **RDD** then you can call `.rdd` on it, that will return an **RDD[C]**. I will edit the answer to provide an example to made it more clear :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to do the calculation at the `rdd` level. Aggregation with the data frame should work:

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(sum(($"needed" > 0).cast("int")).as("positiveCount")).show
+---+-------------+
| id|positiveCount|
+---+-------------+
|  1|            2|
|  3|            2|
|  2|            0|
+---+-------------+
```

If you have to work with RDD, use `row.getInt` or as @Luis' answer `row.getAs[Int]` to get the value with explicit type, and then do the comparison and `reduceByKey`:

```
df.rdd.map(r => (r.getInt(0), if (r.getInt(1) > 0) 1 else 0)).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect
// res18: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,2), (2,0), (3,2))
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in the question, I have to work in `rdd` level. I'll edit the question. Thank you for your time to come up with this solution.